# Post on twitter from ios app

Tags: ios7, twitter

I simply want to post some text and if possible also photo from my ios 7 app. When I click some button and perform action, I want to post silently to twitter. However, if the user has not sign in to twitter, I want to ask for authentication.
I have look through many examples, but could not find any satisfactory guide. Can anbybody please help me out giving guideline and resources?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below link for simple tweet example .

https://github.com/AlexTrott/SLRequest-Tweet