# Swift: How to post to Twitter from iOS app with certain hashtag?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I'm fairly new to posting to social media via Swift in an iOS app but need to be able to post an image to Twitter **under a certain hashtag** (i.e the user's image is always posted under this certain hashtag regardless).

So far, my app can take a picture and access the user's photo library, but I have run into some trouble implementing post to Twitter.
I have looked at the following questions: [Post on twitter from ios app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197570/post-on-twitter-from-ios-app)
[How to make an ios app post to twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666147/how-to-make-an-ios-app-post-to-twitter)

But most of the links referenced are either gone or outdated. I have also looked into Sharekit (http://getsharekit.com) as this would do the posting to Twitter automatically it seems, however Sharekit is deprecated.

Ideally, I would like the user to be able to take their photo (I have this) give it a caption, etc WITHIN THE APP then when they press a button it more or less "silently" posts to Twitter WITH the hashtag that I will have set in the app. I am unsure as to how to accomplish this.

What is the best way/approach to posting an image to Twitter via Swift? The hashtag bit seems to be the more difficult step - how can I "force" a hashtag on the user's post?

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is the **Social** framework and [SLComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/).

Using the `setInitialText(_:)` method you can add text to the tweet, though this doesn't really *force* anything, as the user still has the possibility to edit the tweet before publishing, and it doesn't really work *"silently"* either.

Posting an image is done with the `addImage(_:)` method.